# "chrome.exe" is unkillable and restarts even after uninstalling and restarting computer

Tags: google-chrome

I've been searching for several hours now but so far there are no answers to help with my specific issue, google chrome crashed earlier today and refused to restart with no errors displayed.

After some searching I decided a full reinstall would be justified, but while windows says that I have uninstalled that program, the folder for chrome on my computer is very clearly still there, and even using third party uninstallers they are unable to uninstall what is left of chrome because it is apparently still open.

So I turned to the task manager, found there were two instances of chrome.exe open in my processes, which were unkillable, even when turning to the command prompt and specifically targeting their PID with taskkill.

[whatever you say, command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0czhp.png)

So I'm totally stumped here, anybody have any sort of answer for this?

Comment: Sounds like you may have a portable version of Chrome installed which wont appear in the 'uninstall programs' list. Otherwse something sinister might be going on here too.

Comment: How would I remove this in the event that it was on my computer? As well, how might this have been installed in the first place? Do you know if it comes packed with any other programs?

Comment: search for chrome.exe if you have a Chrome install directory that is not in your add/remove programs list as an option to be uninstalled then you can probably safely remove this directory. Other applications you have installed may have installed a portable chrome in order to embed/render webpages etc. If this is the case removing this may break a part of those applications.

Comment: Newer versions of Chrome do run in the background to provide alerts etc https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en even after you have closed the browser

Comment: Do you know the name of the portable chrome executable? Also, many solutions suggest going in to chrome's settings to turn off it's background functions, but I am unable to start chrome in order to change this setting, and do not know where I would find a config file of some kind to change it the hard way